# Meaning of total

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, terminology, definition

I recently developed a confusion over the word "total" while encountering current, but realized that it arose from my unclear basics.

: when we have an expression involving ,say total charge flown through a given cross section in time interval $t_1$ to $t_2$ , we say that it is *charge flown at $t_2$ - charge flown at $t_1$*. But I think it should have been the area of q-t lying graph b/w $t=t_1$ and $t=t_2$.
I think **change** is a better word but the use of word **total** doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your basics are unclear. What your expression $s(t_2) - s(t_1)$ is measuring is NOT distance, but rather displacement. Distance is the total length of path traveled, and there is no general formula to measure it. Displacement, on the other hand, is the shortest path between two points. The rate of change of displacement is called "velocity".

Comment: I do know that perhaps I should have made it clearer

Comment: "[...] and there is no general formula to measure it." There certainly is an (integral) expression for the path length.

Comment: What I meant was to say this : when we have an expression involving ,say total charge flown through a given cross section in time interval t1 to t2 , we say that it is (charge flown at t2 - charge flown at t1). But I think it should have been the area of q-t lying graph b/w t=t1 and t=t2

Comment: @noah even if there is that is not the question

Comment: @saketkumar It's still worth pointing out factual errors in case someone else reads this. This is not your personal Q&A.

Comment: @noah fair enough :)

Comment: I will edit the question to clarify where the doubt originally arose , as the question that is currently there follows as a moulded version of it